# Took a subject vs Have taken a subject

Tags: present-perfect, perfect-aspect, past-vs-present-perfect

If I am talking about my undergraduate studies, which of the following two is correct?

> I have taken calculus in my undergraduate studies.
>   I took calculus in my undergraduate studies.

Comment: Are you still following this course as an undergraduate?

Comment: @Laure I have already graduated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have finished the course and have already graduated then use **the past**:

- > I took calculus in my undergraduate studies.

  It's a sentence you could have on your resume or implying you have the required knowledge in calculus at undergraduate level.

The **present perfect** would imply you are still following that course:

- > I have taken calculus in my undergraduate studies.

  And it leaves an open situation for the future. For example, justifying why you want to drop or continue a course on calculus after you graduate.